# React axios request: net::Err_Failed

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

Can anyone help me to solve a problem that I have when I'm trying to make a delete request through axios... It gaves me an error message, but its weird because days ago they were working
The error message is in the following picture:

[image]

And according with the function to delete:

```
const handleDeleteFinally = async (e:any) => {
    // Operacion de delete
    console.log(config);
    await axios.delete('https://inventario-services.herokuapp.com/invservice/stock/delet?codigo=' + selectObj, config)  //Request to axios
    .then(res => {
        toast.info('Se ha eliminado el ingrediente. Por favor, recargue la página para ver los cambios.');
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response);
        toast.error('Hay un error desconocido. Por favor intentar mas tarde.');
    });
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: any resolutions? bump

Comment: Well, it seems it was a server issue. I just focused on restart my server and then it worked